# On the definition of divisors in Riemann Surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, riemann-surfaces

The sum notation for a Divisor $D$ in a Riemann Surface $X$ (as in Miranda's *"Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces"*) is
$$
D=\sum_{p\in X} D(p)\cdot p
$$
That is, $D$ assumes the value $D(p)$ at $p$. For example, a principal divisor of $f$ is the divisor
$$
div(f)=D=\sum_{p\in X} ord_p(f)\cdot p
$$

which, if I understood it correctly, means that this divisior is the function
$$
\begin{array}{rcc}
div(f):&X&\rightarrow&\mathbb{Z}\\
&p&\mapsto &ord_p(f)
\end{array}
$$

Now, defining the *divisor of zeroes* and the *divisor of poles* as
$$
div_0(f)=\sum_{p\text{ with }ord_p(f)>0} ord_p(f)\cdot p
$$
and
$$
div_{\infty}(f)=\sum_{p\text{ with }ord_p(f)<0} (-ord_p(f))\cdot p
$$

respectively, how are those functions defined on the points $x\in X$ such that $ord_x(f)\leq 0$ (in the first case) or $ord_x(f)\geq 0$ (on the second)? The question arises since the divisor must be defined in the whole Riemann Surface $X$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For points $p$ that don't appear in the summation defining the divisor of zeros (resp. the divisor of poles) the value of the divisor is zero. This ensures that $\mathrm{div}(f)=\mathrm{div}_0(f)-\mathrm{div}_\infty(f)$.

In general, when working with a free abelian group on some set $X$ (the Riemann surface in your example), if one writes down an expression which sums over a subset of $X$, it is to be understood that the coefficients corresponding to the other elements of $X$ are all zero.

Comment: That's what I first though, but it wasn't so explicit... Thanks!